# ZeroMQ: Can I use kvmsg class to add sequence numbers to messages? If yes, how?

Tags: zeromq

I'm implementing a mechanism to detect packet loss in ZeroMQ **`PUSH/PULL`** socket type.
1) I was wondering if kvmsg can be used for the same?
2) I would like the client to detect gaps in sequence numbers if there are any loss of packets and implement a resend mechanism accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that kvmsg can cope with arbitrary message structures, then yes. Alternatives include Google Protocol Buffers, XML, etc.

In general one does this by adding a field to the messages that you send, perhaps called "sequence". The software you've written for the **`PUSH`** end will set this to zero for the very first message, 1 for the next, incrementing by 1 for each message. The **`PULL`** end then simply checks the sequence.

However, the real question is, why is this required by your application? ZMQ guarantees ( in normal circumstances ) delivery of messages. That's kinda the whole point of it. **`PUSH/PULL`** means that exactly one PULLer will receive a PUSHed message. If you have one **`PUSH`** and one **`PULL`**, every PUSHed message will be delivered in the correct order with no loss to the PULLer, barring catastrophic network failures. AFAIK it will even deal with temporary network problems for you, managing reconnection, etc, and still deliver messages in the correct order.

Messages that cannot be sent because the outgoing queue on the `PUSH` end is full will result in the **`zmq_send()`** returning an error, so the `PUSH` end already knows that a message wasn't sent.

Is there something else more complex about the application?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, as far as we know there no packets lost in PUSH/PULL model but when the rate of send() increases, we've observed packets being dropped silently without PUSH being blocked. Also, I tried killing PULL temporarily and PUSH did block but when I restarted PULL, there were few messages in between that were lost. Is there a solution to it? Not sure how HWM works here.

Comment: @NoName What flags are you passing to zmq_send()?

Comment: I am not setting any flags yet.

Comment: @NoName, OK, without using ZMQ_DONTWAIT, zmq_send() will block until your PULLer is able to receive the message. You won't be able to send any quicker than the PULL can process them. Regarding the kill, ZMQ gets the message as close to the recipient as possible before queuing the message. So it's possible that messages have propagated across the network to get PULL end, but didn't get processed by the PULL before you killed it. Those will be lost

Comment: @NoName, Also the receive buffer HWM size is, by default, 1000 messages. This means that the PULL end will queue up 1000 messages. So if the PULL is being slow to call zmq_recv(), then 1000 will build up inside zmq's own buffers before the PUSH starts having to buffer messages. And when the PUSH buffer fills up too, the zmq_send() will block.

Comment: So is adding sleep() the only option to make sure send and recv applications are in-sync? Because our PULL application does a lot more processing than just receiving and hence the send rate is much faster than recv rate. Also, I observed that adding multiple PULL sockets for load balancing prevents data loss but it's hard to figure out how many PULL sockets we'd need. For all these reasons, we want to implement zero data loss by adding sequencing and resend mechanism since this will be our production data.

Comment: @NoName A sleep shouldn't be necessary if the PUSH is written to block (ie doesn't use ZMQ_DONTWAIT). Are you checking the return from zmq_send()? A sequence number is an excellent way of proving that messages are being lost, or not as the case may be. If you are really losing messages, then trying to work out why is likely easier than writing a lot of code to request a message be resent (ZMQ is supposed to make that unnecessary), even if this means raising a bug report. ZMQ is pretty mature though... Which version?

Comment: @NoName, if the PULLers do varying amounts of processing depending on what the received messages are, then getting the right number of PULLers is always going to be a bit of a guess. Best that you can do is log, and add more next time.

Comment: libzmq version is 4.1.6 and pyzmq version is 16.0.2 . Yes, I did print out the return code from send() . It prints "None" when send() successful and does not return anything when it's blocked. So it's difficult to even know when send() has blocked.

Comment: @NoName, I'm not aware of any specific problems with 4.1.6. 4.2 was a big change - perhaps try that. I suggest you add sequence numbers to your messages, and see what that reveals. Sorry for not having anything more specific; the concept of messages going missing is somewhat contradictory with what ZeroMQ is supposed to do with blocking sockets and no network connectivity problems. It's aims to provide reliable transfers, and we shouldn't have to add our own retry mechanisms on top... Given that, I think for now it is worth persisting with trying to see if messages really are going missing.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I upgraded to 4.2 version and I still see data loss. I have one PUSH socket that is sending around 1000 10Kb messages and one PULL socket and few messages were still lost. With no flags set on PUSH or PULL side.